# why dont compile angular.js with kendo ui grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

hi iam use kendo ui grid but dont compile .iam use mvc with two arrye 
this code use Areas name  profile .

```
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.fa-IR.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <kendo-grid options="gridOptions"></kendo-grid>
</div>
<div id="window"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.gridOptions = {
```

[image]

Comment: you are showing two completely different problems here.  The first, `$ is not defined`, is an indication that you have some problem with JQuery, not angular or kendo.  The second error is most often caused by improperly configuring your angular scripts for minification;  showing how your angular scripts are defined is necessary to trace this error.  You should consider using angular.js instead of angular.min.js when attempting to troubleshoot error messages.

Comment: iam use angular.js but same error

Comment: same *exact* error (`e is undefined`)?  and did you solve the issue with JQuery?